# Add JSON Array to text column in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake, sql-server-json

I want to take the below JSON file (people.json) in Synapse (Datalake)

```
{
"people":
    [
        { "age": 25,
        "id": 2,
        "info": {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Smith" }},
        { "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00",
        "id": 5,
        "info": {
            "name": "Jane",
            "skills": ["SQL","C#","Azure"],
            "surname": "Smith"}}
    ]
}
```

and query it into the below dataset, in particular the last column, skills, which saves all skills as a JSON array in text.

The reason for saving it like is it will make life easier for me when processing this in a logic app.

| id | name | surname | age | skills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | John | Smith | 25 | null |
| 5 | Jane | Smith | null | ["SQL","C#","Azure"] |

To date I have a SQL query which can pull out the id, name, surname and age columns.

But I cannot figure out how to query the skills array into text column.

```
SELECT
    rows.filename() as FileName,
    rows.filepath() as FilePath,
    ID,
    [NAME],
    surname,
    age
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://<storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/debug/people.json',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
        FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
    )
    WITH (
        jsonContent varchar(MAX)
    ) AS [rows]
    cross apply openjson(jsonContent, '$.people') 
    WITH (
        Id INT '$.id',
        [name] NVARCHAR(100) '$.info.name',
        surname NVARCHAR(100) '$.info.surname',
        age INT '$.age'
    )
```

Comment: `, skills nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json` ?